# How to allow OPT and # simultaneously in terminal

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, keybindings

My (UK) MacBook Air keyboard doesn't have # marked. It has ± and §, which I have never used,  but it doesn't have #, which is an extremely common character in computer code. Instead, I have to use the unmarked OPT+3.

I'm using terminal to SSH into a remote server. And through this connection I am loading up the nano editor. In order to access certain nano keyboard shortcuts, I have to go into the terminal settings and allow "Use OPT". But then I can't type # characters.

Comment: Chance the Language input setting to Australian